# First time running a machine learning project

Tags: machine-learning, keras

I am trying to run my first machine learning project, using Keras. I cannot get rid of this error:

```
TypeError: If class_mode="categorical", y_col="Label" column values must be type string, list or tuple.
```

My code looks like this:

```
# Load train images in batches from directory and apply augmentations
        train_data_generator = train_data_generator.flow_from_dataframe(
            train_dataframe,
            IMG_DIRECTORY,
            x_col="Filename",
            y_col="Label",
            target_size=RAW_IMG_SIZE,
            batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
            classes=CLASSES,
            class_mode="categorical")
        # Load validation images in batches from directory and apply rescaling
        val_data_generator = val_data_generator.flow_from_dataframe(
            val_dataframe,
            IMG_DIRECTORY,
            x_col="Filename",
            y_col="Label",
            target_size=RAW_IMG_SIZE,
            batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
            classes=CLASSES,
            class_mode="categorical")
        # Load test images in batches from directory and apply rescaling
        test_data_generator = test_data_generator.flow_from_dataframe(
            test_dataframe,
            IMG_DIRECTORY,
            x_col="Filename",
            y_col="Label",
            target_size=IMG_SIZE,
            batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
            shuffle=False,
            classes=CLASSES,
            class_mode="categorical")
```

These are the only 3 places where I am using y_col and I cannot see what is the problem that results in that error.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can change *dtype* of column *Label* with:

```py
dataframe.Label = dataframe.Label.astype(str)
```

Comment: But if it is not already a string, that's probably for a good reason. That's likely integers or floats, then converting it to strings would be bad. It may prevent the crash, but the predictive power will be trash.

Comment: @user12 No, it (likely) does not.

Comment: I just did not get that error anymore. To be honest, I do not know if it is fine now or not, I am really new into this.

Comment: At user12: Some context on what the actual labels are would be helpful here. Then we could probably give more help regarding your overall setup.

@Keldorn Please explain in more detail why the predictive power would be trash here. I take it, that the problem is an image classification in which converting to Strings would potentially pose no problem. Think of the MNIST Number classification with images. Here I do not see, why strings representing "1", "2", ... would be a problem. That is to say: I see no point in having a numerical instead of a string representation.

Comment: Right, I should not have said converting integers to strings is necessarily bad. For MNIST, this is the right thing to do. But it could be bad on other situations. We don't know from the original question, not enough info here to tell this is the right thing to do.